Does FirebaseAuth require DynamicLinks to be enabled?
Problem
I'm integrating Firebase Authentication to a iOS project and struggling with "Email Link Authentication". Following the guideline I set up everything in Console and run this code to login the user:
func signInWithLink(email: String) async throws {
    let settings = ActionCodeSettings()
    settings.url = URL(string: AppConfig.emailLoginBacklink)!
    settings.iOSBundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    settings.handleCodeInApp = true
    // Implicitly specify `nil` because it's important, see below. 
    settings.dynamicLinkDomain = nil

    try await auth.sendSignInLink(toEmail: email, actionCodeSettings: settings)
}

Errors
I immediately got this error:
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x3038c64c0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x3038c7a50 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 288, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
        {
            domain = global;
            message = "DYNAMIC_LINK_NOT_ACTIVATED : FDL domain is not configured";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "DYNAMIC_LINK_NOT_ACTIVATED : FDL damain is not configured";
}}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error ditails for more information.}

... which means that dynamicLinkDomain shouldn't be nil, I guess?
Meditations & Experiments
I'm aware that Dynamic Links are deprecated and we don't use any. The doc says that if the dynamicLinkDomain is empty the first domain will be used:


dynamicLinkDomain: When multiple custom dynamic link domains are defined for a project, specify which one to use when the link is to be opened via a specified mobile app (for example, example.page.link). Otherwise the first domain is automatically selected.


This implies that FDL should be enabled, isn't it? I hope FB experts will answer below. Meanwhile I tried another configuration:
settings.dynamicLinkDomain = URL(string: "myuniversallink.com")

Here, "myuniversallink.com" is a domain that we use for Universal Links in the app. Not surprisingly, it didn't work:
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSUnderlyingError=0x302f860d0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
        {
            domain = global;
            message = "INVALID_DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "INVALID_DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN";
}, NSUnderlyingError=0x302e10cf0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 228, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}}}}

So, before FDL was not activated, now it's invalid and it looks like there's no way around.
Question
How to enable Email Link Authentication without Dynamic Links?
Configuration
GoogleSignIn - 8.0.0
Firebase - 11.6.0
iOS - 18.0.1
Min iOS supported by project - 16.6

The documentation says "Firebase Auth uses Firebase Dynamic Links when sending a link that is meant to be opened in a mobile application".  If FDL is no longer supported, then it stands to reason that signing in with email links is also not supported.  Since the documentation is not clear on this, you should reach out to Firebase support directly to get clarification.

You can also use the "send feedback" link at the top of any page of Firebase documentation to point out where you think information is lacking or incorrect.  Maybe the documentation just hasn't been properly updated in this case.

Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated, but still supported.
At the moment using email link authentication in Firebase Authentication requires Firebase Dynamic Links to be enabled, which (as you noticed) you cannot do yourself anymore.
From the FAQ on its deprecation and upcoming sunset:

I need to onboard onto Firebase Dynamic Links to enable email link auth in Firebase Authentication. What should I do?
It currently is not possible to newly onboard onto Firebase Dynamic Links if your Firebase project doesn't already have FDL enabled as of the sunset announcement date on August 25th, 2023.
If you need to enable Firebase Dynamic Links to enable email link authentication, please contact Firebase Support and we'll reach back to you to help get you configured.
Note that this continuation of functionality is separate from using Firebase Dynamic Links for the primary use cases of store and web routing, deferred and regular deep-linking, which will be deprecated according to the migration timeline shared above.

So you should reach out to Firebase support to get their help enabling Firebase Dynamic Links on your project for the purpose of using it in email link authentication.

Thanks for the input, but I can't accept this as the right answer even though "Contact Firebase support" instruction seems correct. For me the answer on the SO should be a universal solution that actually works and can be applied in our projects. So I'll connect with the support and come back here when I get this stuff working.

Definitely post back here if you have a better answer, @kelin. I pretty much just copied from the FAQ what you should do. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
